# How can I replace `<div>` to `<h>` tags in a SharePoint site collection?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How can I replace `<div>` to `<h>` tags in a SharePoint site collection?

Could it be done in a console application or a PowerShell script?  Which methods will be able to get the page source?  Or is this code that is in the database?

Comment: I try did everything. I dont now where i get markup

Comment: Can you please be a little clearer as to what exactly you are trying to do? Are you trying to actually update the saved page contents in some bulk way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SharePoint Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473633%28v=office.14%29.aspx) can be accessed from PowerShell or other .NET languages (like C#) - this is covered by many tutorials/examples.

[SPWeb.Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.files.aspx) can be used to enumerate files within a Site and [SPFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.aspx) can read/write a Stream (or String). Likewise, SPSite has methods to enumerate child SPWeb objects.

However, replacing *all* DIV elements with H is likely wrong .. also, some artifacts (like Application Pages or Control Templates) are stored on the File System, not in the Content Database, and so cannot be accessed or modified through the above SPFile approach.

Comment: You'll need to actually open a *real* Site with [SPSite.OpenWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473155.aspx) or similar. Please read the articles that discus when `Dispose` should be called. Anyway, I'm not gonna write the code so take some time and play around with the API and read online resources.

Comment: ok. thanks. But in this method i can change text title example, but how i can change markup div to h2?

Comment: You'll have to read the SPFile contents ([as a Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.openbinary.aspx) that can be wrapped), make the changes, and then re-save the SPFile contents. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c might be useful. Although a "regular expression" might work in a pinch .. note that the ASPX pages are not necessarily valid HTML (much less XHTML).